# Traefik with Let's Encrypt trying to request certificate for localhost

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik

I have Traefik (traefik:1.7.11-alpine) running in a Docker container with a number of services using Let's Encrypt to request certificates to secure them. This works like a charm.

I also have the Treafik web console enabled, but not exposed to the outside world. In other words it is running on localhost. In the log file I see that Traefik is trying to request a certificate for localhost. Is this normal? Can I disable this?

This is the error message

```
time="2019-05-27T07:03:45Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"localhost\" detected thanks to rule \"PathPrefixStrip:/traefik;Host:localhost\" : unable to generate a certificate for the domains [localhost]: acme: error: 400 :: POST :: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/new-order :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:malformed :: Error creating new order :: DNS name does not have enough labels, url: "
```

What I find strange about this is that the web console is running on 8080 and not linked to the https entrypoint in anyway. So I would imagine that Traefik would ignore is when determining for which endpoint it needs to request certificates.

This is the config I'm using:

```
logLevel = "DEBUG"

[traefikLog]

[accessLog]
  [accessLog.filters]
    statusCodes = ["0-600"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
        entryPoint = "https"

  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      minVersion = "VersionTLS12"
      cipherSuites = [
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
      ]

  [entryPoints.traefik]
    address=":8080"
    [entryPoints.traefik.auth]
      [entryPoints.traefik.auth.basic]
        users = ["admin:$apr1$HR4Hj/Zy$fPwTS8LMBqKPpzdzGkyTa/"]

[api]
  entrypoint="traefik"
  dashboard = true
  debug = false

[docker]
  watch = true
  exposedbydefault = false
  domain = "domain.com"
  network = "web"

[acme]
  email = "info@domain.com"
  storage = "acme.json"
  entryPoint = "https"
  onHostRule = true
  [acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "http"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just documenting the solution here for anyone that runs into this problem. The Traefik Docker Compose examples have the label `traefik.enable=true` set, which causes Traefik to try and request a certificate for the service if you enable Let's Encrypt. Even for localhost :-( Setting the value to `false` solves the problem.